# php bad requests protection

Tags: php, bad-request, ddos

I just found my site bening attacked by random urls:

`mysite.com/index.php?S8QGLe1=581&v8FJPJy0S5=kHspRdtaeLv&YbdIFl1lL`
`mysite.com/index.php?kkFPD=lvVJivSMdsdfXK&LlRlQQ6=6gb`
`mysite.com/index.php?WwTl0J=La7&yQw=mr1XO1d42n0eyhvxv8D&7LXxO=OYa`

and when I click on one of them (index.php) opens and ignores the text after it!

how do I make php gives 404 error to urls that has random text after (index.php)?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This will send a 'Forbidden' error for evry request with any kind of Query string

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" ".*"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "index.php" /*  it's the index.php file */
RewriteRule "(.*)" '-' [F]
```

Comment: thank you, works great. but how can I add exception to allow some Query string like (?page-?module)

Comment: Add the following line to be something like:  
   
 ```RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}"  !"(page|module)"```